# Windows 7 and international Dvorak keyboard layout with dead keys?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout, dvorak, usability, dead-keys

I cannot find such a feature in Keyboard layout list. 
It would be so much easier if the layout is built in the system because I cannot install 3rd-party layouts in all environments. 
I need

- first-level or second-level dead-keys with Scandinavian letters (A with dots, O with dots)
- regions concerned: German, Sweden, Finland, Denmark, Norway, ...

It would be great if you can change some file little in the system to enable such dead key features.

OS: Windows 7

Answer (score 2):

You can use [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com) to create a series of [dead keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key) that will allow you to include whatever accents you require.  For example, the following script will allow you to use the <kbd>~</kbd> and <kbd>n</kbd> keys to make **ñ** or **Ñ**.

```
~::
Input, key, L1, {delete}{esc}{backspace}
if(key=="n"){
    Send {Asc 164} 
}
else if(key=="N"){
    Send {Asc 165} 
}
else {
    Send {Asc 126}%key%
}
return
```

The `~::` line grabs the `~` keystroke, then the `input` command grabs the next 1 character (L1) and assigns it to the variable `key`.  The <kbd>Delete</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>,and <kbd>Backspace</kbd> keys are all listed as escape keys, which will return just the original `~` that was typed.  Otherwise, if you type a lowercase `n` the script will send the ASCII code for **ñ** (`Send {Asc 130}`), and typing an uppercase `N` sends the ASCII code for **Ñ**.  Typing anything else returns the `~` and the next letter you had typed (the final `else` command sends the ASCII for `~` followed by the contents of the `key` variable).

For accents that aren't in the base ASCII, you need to use Unicode, like so:

```
^::
Input, key, L1, {delete}{esc}{backspace}
if(key=="u"){
    Send {Asc 150} 
}
else if(key=="U"){
    Send {U+00DB} 
}
else {
    Send {Asc 94}%key%
}
return
```

Note the difference in command when writing the capital **Û**.

You can chain as many of these together you need, using `if ... else if` commands for everything that uses the same dead key stroke.  Just make sure to include the final `else` statement and the `return` command at the end before going on to the next dead key and set of accents.  The downside to this is that you need to explicitly spell out all the dead keys and accented characters you want to use.  Fortunately, they all follow the same pattern, making setting it up simple, if possibly tedious.

---

More on the AutoHotKey `Send` command: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm

More on the AutoHotKey `Input` command: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Input.htm

ASCII table: http://www.asciitable.com/

Unicode table: https://unicode-table.com/en/

Comment: How much extra do you need to install for Autohotkey?

Comment: AutoHotKey itself takes about 10MB for the 64-bit version.  You can also install it on another computer, then compile your script into a stand-alone EXE which does not require installation.  Size of the compiled EXE is usually pretty small (1-2 MB), but it ultimately depends on the length of your script.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install AllChars.  Very nifty little app and very flexible.  Can't remember it much, yet very flexible in formatting the keyboard.  Used it in '98, XP and . . . yeah, those two.  Don't know about 7.  In 7 you can activate US International and if I remember correctly you can also do that for other layouts.

Then you will have to get facile with changing layouts on the fly.  You should find a language toolbar on Desktop or in Taskbar.  Make the simplest and easiest Change layout key sequence - least, shortest finger movements.  Once you have the sequences, (changing and typing) it becomes habit.  I blind type between English (South African) and US International for Afrikaans diacritics.  Not as complex as yours and yet you have to get it into muscle memory.

Good luck!

Comment: Take a look at [How do I write a good answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) and edit your answer

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Dvorak Layout on MacOsx since 10 years, and I recently also have a PC on windows.
I have manage to create a layout with dead keys using the Microsoft Keyboard Layout Editor.
I have put the source code here : https://github.com/adrienleroy/windows-dvorak-deadkeys-layout